# Cannot set width of bootstrap card-body

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I tried everything, from documentations, last 10 stack overflow answers, and nothing helped. I tried with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I tried with @@meedia in style, I tried with w-100 on card body, everything and nothing helps. I need whole application like this to have normal width so please help. I have VS 2022 with .NET 6 onboard.

I just cannot make when I start an application (on desktop) and go on F12, put on mobile. The card-body is really long and I want to set width of card-body to mobile screen size.

Code is this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaKuce">Prodaja kuća</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaStanova">Prodaja stanova</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaNekretninaZaOdmor">Prodaja nekretnina za odmor</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the final result is still the same.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

The `w-100` just sets the `width` to be `100%` of the *parent* container, and in this case that is specified by `col-sm-4`. Bootstrap makes use of 12 columns, and divides the content up into that based on the `col-` classes. If you want your columns to each occupy a full row, then simply make use of `col-12`.

If you want them to occupy the full width on mobile, but three columns on desktop, you can make use of the combination of `col-sm-12` and `col-md-4` as seen in the following example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaKuce">Prodaja kuća</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaStanova">Prodaja stanova</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaNekretninaZaOdmor">Prodaja nekretnina za odmor</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div
```

Comment: This is not helped. I put you screenshot again.